# Angular Translate Routes

Tags: angular

i use ngx-translate and switch my language with

```
<a href="/de-de/">DE
<a href="/en-en/">EN
```

I want to ask if it is possible to translate the routes.

For example:

```
en-en/home
de-de/zuhause
```

The route needs to be changed in the app-routing module.
My idea is to use the app resolver to translate the Routing Config.

Best,
Daniel

Comment: Routes are evaluated at build time. I don't think it would be possible to translate them

Comment: Check this plugin: https://github.com/gilsdav/ngx-translate-router It does exactly what you want. Your question is quite broad so don't expect a more specific answer.

Comment: I am using this plugin but i am not able to translate routes with it.